# .htaccess in subfolder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I install a new cms (phpmydirectory) in a subfolder. In the root there is a wordpress with friendly url's.

When I activate the friendly url's in phpmydirectory, I get an 404 error in the categories and locations, but no in the listings. The 404 error appear in the blog template and URL.

How fix the -htaccess so the subfolder read the .htaccess in the subfolder ando no the one in root?

Comment: At the very least, post one of the .htaccess rewrite rules. Posting both would be even better.

Answer (score 0):

Apache always reads all `.htaccess` files along the path to the root directory. This cannot be changed (except for disallowing use of `.htaccess` alltogether). The best you can get is making sure that rules for `mod_rewrite` in the parent directory do not apply. This might be possible using

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

as the last rule in your `phpmydirectory` directory.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the subdirectory specified as the $BASE_URL in your defaults.php file for PMD? I'm operating with a similar setup right now, and did not have to make adjustments to the .htaccess file. However, its not competing with a Wordpress install in the root directory (its an older version of phpmydirectory instead), so that might be causing a different issue than my setup.